# Swift google map auto suggestion dropdown styling

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am using GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController for auto suggestion of address. How can I style it? like reducing font size and changing background etc

This is the code

```
resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
        resultsViewController?.delegate = self


        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
        searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
```